# Can I pre-load files into my NextJS project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a 22mb JSON file (all text) that I'm using to experiment with some beginner ML patterns. I'm currently loading it in `getStaticProps()` and returning the end result as a prop. But it's taking quite some time to load the page. It's taking between 30-40seconds each time. Any way I can cut down the build/load time?

Would moving the logic to `/api` and making requests to it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, you can. 
You need to split your data into small parts. Each part should not exceed 4MB (better to use 2-3 MB). Once you show your very first data, for each next request you can populate the page with next data. But this approach will not reduce your time, only `first content` will be faster.

Comment: Best way is to split the data to smaller chunks.You alsan can use the /api